# Как можно оптимизировать код?

Tags: python, python-3.x, алгоритм

Как можно уменьшить время работы данного кода:

Он ищет из введенных чисел равные соседние,затем при их наличие потом выводит NO

Где n- кол-во строк

```py
n = int(input())
s = []
while nraz < n:
    s += [int(a) for a in input().split()]
    for i in range(0, len(s) - 1):
        if s[i] == s[i + 1]:
            data += 1
    s = []
    nraz += 1
if data > 0:
    print('No')
else:
    print('Yes')
```

UPD:

Ввод:

```
5
1 2 1 2 1
1
2 3
4
5 6
```

Вывод:

```
YES
```

Ввод:

```
7
5
1 2 1 2 1
1
3 2
4
6 6
7
```

Вывод:

```
NO
```

Comment: Приведите пример входных и выходных данных.

Comment: Добавил ввод.Фишка в том,что каждую нужно проверять отдельно.Т.К Конец одной и начало второй-соседи в одном массиве.Но не в одной строке

Comment: Это пример какого-то другого, может более полного фрагмента кода.

Comment: Да,могу кинуть полный код.Но там и другие переменные(Чтобы понять их смысл,нужно кинуть текст задачи)Просто именно это меня интересует

Comment: Наоборот. Приведите минимально возможный ввод-вывод (только для этого фрагмента), чтобы читающему было проще понять. что вы имеете и хотите получить.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python предпочитает декларативное манипулирование, а не индексное.

```
from operator import eq

arr = [1, 2, 3, 3, 4]

if any(map(eq, arr, arr[1:])):
    print('No')
else:
    print('Yes')
```

функция `any` ленивая, т.е. прервет выполнение, как только встретит первый истинный результат.

Comment: Ну просто если до этого для каждой строки будет YES,а в конце будет 6 6,например,то это не верно же.Там по итоге нужно сказать,подходит(если нет соседей-YES) или NO

Comment: @potemin Поясните. Не понял. Желательно с примером входных данных.

Comment: Добавил второй вывод

Comment: @potemin Извините, перепутал Y/N. Исправил.

Comment: Я бред написал.У Вас все нормально:)Способ чудесный,но все равно падает из-за РанТайма)

Answer (score 0):

Единственное, что можно сделать - досрочный выход при нахождении равных соседей:

```
s += [int(a) for a in input().split()]
        for i in range(0, len(s) - 1):
            if s[i] == s[i + 1]:
                print('Yes')
                return;
        print('No')
```

Врятли можно ещё улучшить.

Comment: Просто там нужно будет считать все значения(в разных строках),а уже потом вывести Yes или No

Comment: А смысл их читать до конца ввода, если уже известно, что ответ Yes? Что бы потом ни ввели, ответ уже не изменится. Можно считать, но не анализировать, что я и предлагаю.

Comment: Суть в том,что в одной строке может быть(1 2 3) Ответ:YES.А в следующей уже 1 2 2.Ответ NO.Но если мы принтанем yes,то уже будет не верно

Comment: Как тут может быть Yes, если нет одинаковых соседей?

Comment: Там логика немного другая,я задачу не вставил,сорян.Если соседей нет,то YES(т.е по условию такое может быть)

Comment: Тогда отредактируйте, пожалуйста, вопрос так, чтобы из него было ясно, какую задачу должен решать код. Иначе ответы будут невпопад.